# MySQL no root/super user

Tags: mysql, terminal, root, privileges

There is no superuser configured for my MySQL setup on Lion OS X. I've tried purging MySQL from my macbook, to no avail.

The only way I can initialize mysql is by executing it through the terminal without any username or password. I'm trying to create a **root** user as a workaround, but I don't have privileges.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;

+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| @localhost     |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

How do I go about reinstating a default **root** user, seeing as I do not have any privileges?

Comment: I'm working through a similar problem and documenting my progress here https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=58828

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [resetting permissions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix) tutorial on the MySQL docs.

Comment: This tutorial is for resetting the root password. I'm trying to reset the root user. Instead of ''@localhost, I want root@localhost.

Comment: The tutorial allows you to run any query w/o a permissions model. Swap your query in instead of they one they suggest.

Comment: I think ohBoy has a valid point.  You can't do anything "WHERE User='root'" (as the link suggests) if there's no root user.  "Swap your query" is a little vague.  Also why is this closed as off topic?  It's a great question as it's common to eliminate the "root" user for extra security.  Still looking for a solution!